# Automatic room light controller with IR sensor

Tags: optoelectronics

[image]

([Schematic source: Electronics Hub](https://www.electronicshub.org/ir-sensor/#Obstacle_Sensing_Circuit_or_IR_Sensor_Circuit))

In this circuit sensor is not working.using (4*1.5)v cells as supply.without connecting the transmitter and receiver elements,in the o/p led glows.i have connected led between  two o/p terminals then after regulating the pot led varies between 0-2.1v(approx),but the sensor is not working at all.please help....

---

I have measured the voltage b/w inverting and non-inverting I/p that was about 1-1.3v when adjusting the pot.But it shows without working the sensor (photodiode).no response against obstacles.

Comment: What do you mean "the sensor is not working"? What do you expect to happen? Can you elaborate on how you came up with the design (e.g., why do you believe this SHOULD be working?)

Comment: I mean that ir proximity sensor which is used to detect any object or any kind of obstacles does not work.after setting the pot in a particular value,if i put any object between the transmitter and receiver...led does not fluctuate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your problem, but I can give you a hint for debugging your circuit. You can measure the voltage at pin 3 (+) of the op-amp with a voltmeter. If you illuminate the photodiode, the voltage should rise from 0V up to ~1V. If this works, then your photodiode setup is ok and there must be some issue with the op-amp. Otherwise your photodiode is not working (what type is it?)

Answer (score 0):

> without connecting the transmitter and receiver elements, in the o/p
>   led glows.

Zero offset voltage is the characteristic of an op-amp.If the value of two inputs is different, then Op-AMP will try to balance the imbalance between those two inputs by either sourcing or sinking a current at the output. So, measuring the voltage of inverting and a non-inverting input will help.

Comment: I have measured the voltage b/w inverting and non-inverting I/p that was about 1-1.3v when adjusting the pot.But it shows without working the sensor (photodiode).no response against obstacles.

Comment: that's the point I have mentioned. You need to make it equal or else, there will be a current flow.

Comment: When the light emitted by the IR LED is incident on the photodiode after hitting an object, the resistance of the photodiode falls down from a huge value. One of the input of the op – amp is at threshold value set by the potentiometer. The other input to the op-amp is from the photodiode’s series resistor. When the incident radiation is more on the photodiode, the voltage drop across the series resistor will be high. In the IC, both the threshold voltage and the voltage across the series resistor are compared. If the voltage across the resistor series to photodiode is greater than that of the